# Creating a map of maps from a map Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `Map<String, List<SomeClassA>>` that I'm trying to convert into a `Map<String, Map<String, List<SomeWrapperOfClassA>>>` and I'm just having so much trouble wrapping my head around how to do this.

Really, all the information needed to create the map should be in the objects of type SomeClassA - say

```
SomeClassA:
   String attributeA;
   String attributeB;
   SomeClassB someOtherInfo;

SomeClassB:
   String attribute C;
```

And I want to say it's a map based on this:

`Map<attributeA's values,Map<attribute C vals, List SomeWrapperOfClassA>>`
where the list is only of SomeWrapperClassA that has those values of attributeA and attributeB. I was thinking it might have to do with groupingBy, but I'm not too familiar with how to do it in such a way that its nested like this.

(or for the sake of simplicity, any help just getting the original list of SomeClassA into a `Map<String, Map<String, List<SomeClassA>>>` would already be a huge help.

I  haven't quite gotten the hang of Java 8 and the more complex streaming concepts yet, so some help would be greatly appreciated. I'm only familiar with the basics.

Comment: Maybe you should check out Google Guava's Multimap: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you meant by:
 `Map<String, Map<String, List<SomeClassA>>>`, what is the key here to group by? in general if you want to group  `List<SomeClassA>` by say attributeA from SomeClassA you can do this:

```
 List<SomeClassA>.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(someClsA-> someClsA.getAttributeA()));
```

Comment: well, for the inner map, we want to group by some attribute C, and for the outer map, it would be by attribute A - both attributes are things that could be obtained by the objects in the list.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your questions correctly I would express it as follows:

Given:

```
class ClassA {
    public String getA();
    public ClassB getB();
}

class ClassB {
    public String getC();
}

Map<String, List<ClassA>> input;
```

How would I create a `Map<String, Map<String, List<ClassB>>` where the key of the inner map is the result of `getA`?

If that's correct then you aren't looking to change the keys of the outer map at all. That makes it a good candidate for `Map.replaceAll`. For clarity I've split the collector into a separate method so it's clear what's happening:

```
input.replaceAll(listA.stream().collect(mapCollector()));

private Collector<A, ?, Map<String, List<B>> mapCollector() {
    return Collectors.groupingBy(ClassA::getA,
        Collectors.mapping(ClassA::getB,
            Collectors.toList()));
}
```

Explaining the method it says group `A`s by `getA` as key, then collect those `A`s by mapping using `getB` then putting in a list.

If you particularly want a new map (rather than changing the original one) then:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<ClassB>>> output = input.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().stream().collect(mapCollector()));
```

Comment: `Map.replaceAll` expects a `BiFunction` as its argument, but anyway, I doubt that an in-place change is intended, as the source type `List<SomeClassA>` and the result type `Map<String, List<SomeWrapperOfClassA>>` aren’t compatible.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not entirely clear what you want to achieve. Apparently, the keys of your source map are irrelevant and you only want to process the `SomeClassA` instances contained in the value lists. So, the first step is to stream over the map’s values, i.e. `sourceMap.values().stream()`, then flatten this `Stream<List<SomeClassA>>` to a `Stream<SomeClassA>` via `flatMap(List::stream)`.

Grouping these `SomeClassA` instances by one of their properties works indeed straight-forwardly via `groupingBy`, which needs another nested `groupingBy` to group each group further by “Attribute C”:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<SomeClassA>>> resultMap
    = sourceMap.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SomeClassA::getAttributeA,
                     Collectors.groupingBy(a->a.getSomeOtherInfo().getAttributeC())));
```

To convert the `SomeClassA` instances to `SomeWrapperClassA` instances, we need another nested collector for the innermost `groupingBy`; the `mapping` collector allows to map the values before transferring to another collector, which has to be the `toList()` collector, which was formerly implicit.

Now, it might be better to start using `import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;`

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<SomeWrapperClassA>>> resultMap
  = sourceMap.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(groupingBy(SomeClassA::getAttributeA, groupingBy(
      a -> a.getSomeOtherInfo().getAttributeC(),
      mapping(a->new SomeWrapperClassA(a.getAttributeA(),a.getAttributeB()), toList()))));
```